# my .append() function didn't work properly I couldn't spot why (beginner level Python)

Tags: python, debugging, append

im a beginner programmer and im trying to make a simple blackjack game just for exercise in Python 3.10 using PyCharm CE but I wasn't able to solve a problem. The problem is my player_draw_card() function is not drawing a card. I wanted to put the whole code in case I miss something but I also highlighted the important parts (imo) with #'s.

```
import random


cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10] #extra 10's stands for J,Q,K and 11 is Ace
player_score = 0
computer_score = 0
player_cards = []
computer_cards = []

#############################################################
def player_draw_card():
  index = random.randint(0, 12)  # Selecting a random index from cards for player
  player_cards.append(cards[index])  # Adding the selected 1 card to player_cards
#############################################################

def computer_draw_card():
  index = random.randint(0, 12)  # Selecting a random index from cards for computer
  computer_cards.append(cards[index])  # Adding the selected 1 card to computer_cards


def calculate_player_score():  # Calculate player's score everytime it draws a card to prevent confusion when you have multiple Aces.
  player_score = sum(player_cards)
  if player_score > 21 and (11 in player_cards):
      index_of_11 = player_cards.index(11)
      player_cards[index_of_11] = 1
      player_score = sum(player_cards)


def calculate_computer_score():  # Calculate computer's score everytime it draws a card to prevent confusion when you have multiple Aces.
  computer_score = sum(computer_cards)
  if computer_score > 21 and (11 in computer_cards):
    index_of_11 = computer_cards.index(11)
    computer_cards[index_of_11] = 1
    computer_score = sum(computer_cards)

#####################################################################
def blackjack():
  player_lost = False
  player_score = 0
  computer_score = 0
  player_cards = []
  computer_cards = []
  player_draw_card() #################
  player_draw_card() #################
###################################################################### 
#**Problem is not beyond here most likely, cause when I run it step by step**
#**player_draw_card() function didnt add anything.**
##########################################################################
  print(f"Your cards: {player_cards}")
  calculate_player_score()
#####################################
  computer_draw_card()
  print(f"Computer's first card: {computer_cards}")
#####################################
#**My computer_draw_card() is also not working btw but they build in same way so**
#**if we can fix the player_draw_card() function, we can fix the computer_draw_card() aswell**
#######################################
  calculate_computer_score()
  player_wants_more = True
  while player_wants_more:
    y_or_n = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:").lower()
    if y_or_n == "n":
      player_wants_more = False
    if y_or_n == "y":
      player_draw_card()
      calculate_player_score()
      if player_score > 21:
        player_lost = True
        player_wants_more = False
              
  if player_lost == True:
    print("You lost!\n")
    restart = input("If you want to play again type 'y' if you want to finish the game type 'n'")
    if restart == "y":
      blackjack()
  while computer_score < 17:
    computer_draw_card()
    calculate_computer_score()
  if computer_score < player_score:
    print("You win!\n")
  elif player_score < computer_score:
    print("You lose")
  else:
    print("It's a draw!")
  y_or_n = input("Type 'y' if you want to play another game and 'n' if you dont.").lower()
  if y_or_n == 'y':
    blackjack()
  else:
    print("Bye")
blackjack() ############################### This is the only function that is called 
########################################### Except the ones that are called in def's
```

I tried looking it step by step in pythontutor.com and it seems like """player_cards.append(cards[index])  # Adding the selected 1 card to player_cards""" line of code, doesn't add anything to player_cards

What seems strange to me though is, I tried a simpler version for drawing card with following.

```
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
player_cards = []
import random

def player_draw_card():
    index = random.randint(0, 12)  # Selecting a random index from cards for player
    player_cards.append(cards[index])
player_draw_card()
print(player_cards)
```

And it works, it adds a random number to the player_cards. What is the problem someone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `player_cards` list twice. Once it is defined on line 7, and then again inside the `blackjack()` method on line 41.

What happens is that you are creating two differently scoped variables `player_cards`. When you're calling the `player_draw_card()` from the `blackjack()` method, the `player_draw_card()` doesn't know about the `player_cards` in your `blackjack()` method. It looks up the name `player_cards` in its own scope, then in its parent scope, where it is defined.

You can solve this in two ways:

- Remove the `player_cards` declaration inside your `blackjack()` method. This will make all the methods use the global list.
- Add a parameter to `player_draw_card(player_cards: list[int])` method and pass the list from your `blackjack()` method. In this case you won't need the global list anymore. IMO this is over-complication for this code example.

Note: You have the same issue with the `compiter_cards` list.

Comment: Oh thanks so much for answering, i actually added the player_cards at line 7 after I got an error player_cards not defined. It happens because i mention them in my defined functions before player_cards is defined. My logic for adding them on line 41 was If the player wants to restart, I need to empty their hand to have a fresh start. But I can see my method is wrong now. I changed the line 41 player_cards definition to player_cards.clear() and it's solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: Now I realized that same problem will occur with the player_score and computer_score. They are defined twice aswell. Thanks man, great lesson for me